# No reconoce Requests en proyecto de Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mvc

Tengo los siguientes métodos en un controlador:

```
public function edit2($id)
{
    $post       = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);

    $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->pluck('name', 'id');
    $tags       = Tag::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();

    return view('admin.posts.edit2', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));
}

public function update2(PostUpdateRequest2 $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);

    $post->user_id         = $post->user_id;
    $post->excerpt         = $post->excerpt;
    $post->body            = $post->body;

    $post->save(); 

    //IMAGE 
    if($request->file('file')){
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',  $request->file('file'));
        $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
    }

    //NOTAS
    if($request->file('file2')){
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('notas',  $request->file('file2'));
        $post->fill(['file2' => asset($path)])->save();
    }

    //TAGS
    $post->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));

    return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)->with('info', 'Entrada actualizada con éxito');
}
```

Tengo dos update: update y update2 cada uno con un request, PostUpdateRequest y PostUpdateRequest2 respectivamente. No encuentro la razon de porque no me reconoce el PostUpdateRequest2, me sale el siguiente mensaje

> "Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PostUpdateRequest2 does not exist"

Pero cuando cambio el request en Update2 por PostUpdateRequest, este si lo reconoce.

**EDIT1:** Esta seria la ruta de los request:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El request que quiero utilizar es el PostUpdateRequest2 en Update2 pero obtengo el mensaje de error colocado anteriormente, sin embargo si utilizo el PostUpdateRequest en Update2 no obtengo ningún error, pero no quiero usar este request sino el otro.

**EDIT2:** Dev. Joel tiene razon, solo me faltaba importarle el request PostUpdateRequest2, por eso no lo encontraba.

Comment: ¿cuál es la ruta de dichos Request? No veo además dónde estás llamando a PostUpdateRequest.

Comment: ¿Estas importando el request _(use App\Http\Requests\PostUpdateRequest2)_ ? ¿La ruta es correcta?

Comment: Kinafune agrega informacion necesaria, responde a las preguntas de Shaz y Dev. Joel por favor.